# If then logic with && ||

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic

Can someone explain to me or point me to documentation as to why the following function doesn't work?

```js
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
var z = 1;

function logicTest() {
  if ((x && y && z) === 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(logicTest())
```

I know that I can type it out the long way as follows:

```js
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
var z = 1;

function logicTest() {
  if (x === 1 && y === 1 && z === 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(logicTest())
```

But I'm really trying to understand why the first doesn't work and also if there is a better way of typing the second if/then statement or if that is just the way it will always have to be.

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation for any language is not going to be able to list all of the things that are not valid syntax.

Comment: Because  `&&` and `||` works with boolean operators where as in first case you are trying to operate them on integer values.

Where as in your second case, individual conditions resolves to booleans and working as is.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: @DavidThomas no, the `&&` operator in JavaScript does **not** evaluate to a boolean value. The result value depends on the *input* values; in this case that expression will yield a number (`1`).

Comment: @DavidThomas yeah I just realized that `1 && 2` in console gives me 2 instead of `true`

Comment: @Pointy: my silly comment removed! I hadn't considered it that way; this is one of the many problems of learning JavaScript almost entirely by accident. My bad :)

Comment: @DavidThomas JavaScript is weird that way, though of all its idiosyncrasies I think this particular quirk was a really good idea.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/208/comparison-operations/828/logic-operators-with-non-boolean-values-boolean-coercion#t=201702281311439403736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
((x && y && z) === 1)
```

first involves the evaluation of `(x && y && z)`. To evaluate that, JavaScript tests, in sequence, the values of `x`, `y`, and `z`. If, left to right, one of those values when coerced to boolean is `false`, evaluation stops  with that (uncoerced) value as the value of the whole thing. Otherwise, the value of that subexpression will be the value of `z`, because it's the last subexpression in the `&&` sequence.

In this case, `x`, `y`, and `z` are all non-zero numbers, so the overall result will be `1`, because `z` is `1`.

What you seem to want to be able to do is test whether all of a set of subexpressions are equal to the same value. That, as you've found, can only be determined by explicit comparison. It's also something that could be done by creating a list and then using array functions to perform the tests, which would be useful when there are more than just three subexpressions to test.

Also, on a stylistic note:

```
function logicTest() {
  if (x === 1 && y === 1 && z === 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Performing tests with relational operators like `===` generates boolean values. It's more concise to take advantage of that:

```
function logicTest() {
  return x === 1 && y === 1 && z === 1;
}
```

Comment: I guess you can link Docs as well: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/208/comparison-operations/828/logic-operators-with-non-boolean-values-boolean-coercion#t=201702281311439403736

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the explanation and the better way to write the code.